# Number of seconds since midnight

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I wrote the below code to get the number of seconds since midnight.

However, I'm not great with the C time date structs. Is there a simpler way of doing this using a standard C++ library?

```
// Get today's date
time_t aTime = time(NULL);

// Set the time to midnight
struct tm* tm = localtime(&aTime);
tm->tm_sec = 0;
tm->tm_min = 0;
tm->tm_hour = 0;
tm->tm_isdst = -1;
time_t midnight = mktime(tm);

// Create object representing now
struct timespec now;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);

// Number of seconds (now) since Epoch
const uint64_t nowSecsSinceEpoch = now.tv_sec;

// Number of seconds (now) since midnight = seconds (now) since Epoch minus seconds (at midnight) since Epoch
const uint64_t nowSecsSinceMidnight = nowSecsSinceEpoch - midnight;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on if you mean time since midnight UTC, or time since midnight local time, or perhaps in some non-local, far away time zone.

This is also made much easier in C++20.  But there exists a [preview of the C++20 parts of the `<chrono>` library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that can be used with C++11-17.

### Time since midnight UTC

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto now = system_clock::now();
    auto today = floor<days>(now);
    auto tod = duration_cast<seconds>(now - today);
}
```

This simply gets the current time (UTC), truncates it to a days-precision `time_point`, and then subtracts the two and truncates that difference to seconds precision.

### Time since local midnight

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto now = current_zone()->to_local(system_clock::now());
    auto today = floor<days>(now);
    auto tod = duration_cast<seconds>(now - today);
}
```

This version finds your computer's currently set local time zone, and then gets the current local time via the time_zone's `to_local()` member function.  And then proceeds as before.

### Time since some other midnight

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto now = locate_zone("Australia/Sydney")->to_local(system_clock::now());
    auto today = floor<days>(now);
    auto tod = duration_cast<seconds>(now - today);
}
```

Finally, this version finds the time_zone associated with Sydney Australia, and then uses *that* time zone and proceeds as before.

The [C++20 preview `<chrono>` library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) is free and open-source.  It puts everything in namespace date, and in two headers (and one source):

- `date.h`:  A header-only library that will do the UTC part, but has no time zone support.
- `tz.h`:  For the time zone support.  This requires [some installation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).

Comment: It's all local time